# Undefined Control Sequence \maketitle ... par

Tags: errors, titles

I'm new to LateX (first day playing around with it). Downloaded a sample (for a thesis) and I get the following error:

[image]

I've tried googling around, but it seems like undefined control sequence could mean many things. Any ideas to what it means? Please write a comment if any more info is needed and I'll edit the question.

Comment: Whithout seeing your code it's pretty hard to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: We really need to see a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In this case it's `\@degree` that is the undefined control sequence (last command on the line after *undefined ...*). However, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) makes this much easier to answer in more detail. (Generally, always create a minimal example demonstrating whatever the problem is, makes things easier for us.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should define (before `\maketitle`) something like

```
\degree{Master of Universe}
```

otherwise the internal `\@degree` is not defined which is used for the title.

Comment: Whatever thesis class is being used should have prepared for this. It should contain a line like `\def\@degree{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\degree given}\@ehc}`. Then a reasonably explanatory error message would be produce.

Comment: this didn't work for me. i am getting the same error. any ideas?